# Is intent.getExtras.getInt() same as intent.getIntExtra()?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, extras

I am confused:

Is `intent.getExtras.getInt()` same as `intent.getIntExtra()`?

If I start my service using `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, will the extras
be included in the intent?

I get `NullPointerException` on restart of my crashed service, which I find strange....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Intent source code :

```
private Bundle mExtras;

// [...]

public int getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue) {
    return mExtras == null ? defaultValue :
    mExtras.getInt(name, defaultValue);
}

public Bundle getExtras() {
    return (mExtras != null)
        ? new Bundle(mExtras)
       : null;
}
```

So yes. Same thing except `getExtras()` may return null.

Comment: In order to return a copy of the Bundle, then, the original mExtras Bundle remains not modified.

Answer (score 1):

They are not quite identical. As you are finding out, the first variant will cause a NPE if `intent.getExtras()` returns `null`. The second variant does its own null-checking, and returns the default value if the extra is not present.

I can't speculate as to why you aren't getting the expected Extras without seeing more code.

Comment: I understand. Though it is the expected behaviour that the extras get redelivered as well on restart of service? Correct?